# Use RACCommand with Asynchronous Network Operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa, raccommand

I'm using `UAGitHubEngine` to access GitHub's API. I want to write a functional reactive app to fetch some data. I'm relying on on the code [here](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) to set up an asynchronous network request. What I'm looking for is the team id of some team named "General". I can do the filtering/printing part OK:

```
[[self.gitHubSignal filter:^BOOL(NSDictionary *team) {
    NSString *teamName = [team valueForKey:@"name"];
    return [teamName isEqualToString:@"General"];
}] subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *team) {

    NSInteger teamID = [[team valueForKey:@"id"] intValue];

    NSLog(@"Team ID: %lu", teamID);
}];
```

But setting up the command is a mystery to me:

```
self.gitHubCommand = [RACCommand command];

self.gitHubSignal = [self.gitHubCommand addSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id value) {
    RACSignal *signal = ???

    return signal;
}];
```

How do I set up the signal block to return a signal that pushes an event when some asynchronous network call returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was in `RACReplaySubject`, which [AFNetworking uses](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/reactive-cocoa-playground/blob/master/src/reactive-cocoa-playground/AFNetworking/Api.m#L28-L51) to wrap its asynchronous requests.

```
self.gitHubCommand = [RACCommand command];

self.gitHubSignals = [self.gitHubCommand addSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id value) {
    RACReplaySubject *subject = [RACReplaySubject subject];

    [engine teamsInOrganization:kOrganizationName withSuccess:^(id result) {

        for (NSDictionary *team in result)
        {
            [subject sendNext:team];
        }

        [subject sendCompleted];            
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        [subject sendError:error];
    }];

    return subject;
}];
```

Since `addSignalBlock:` returns a signal of signals, we need to subscribe to the next signal it emits.

```
[self.gitHubSignals subscribeNext:^(id signal) {
    [signal subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *team) {
        NSInteger teamID = [[team valueForKey:@"id"] intValue];

        NSLog(@"Team ID: %lu", teamID);
    }];
}];
```

Finally, the `addSignalBlock:` block isn't executed until the command is executed, which I managed with the following:

```
[self.gitHubCommand execute:[NSNull null]];
```